# Data filtered differently in sql and crystal reports

Tags: sql, postgresql, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

Problem arises when filtering string columns with symbols '-'.
For example query bellow returns ~280 rows:

```
"SELECT code FROM client WHERE code >= 'M-SOLUTIONS' AND code <= 'MUZIKOS'"
```

but CR with record selection bellow only returns 20 rows:

```
{client.code} >= 'M-SOLUTIONS' AND {client.code} <= 'MUZIKOS'
```

If I put 'Lxxx' instead of 'M-SOLUTIONS' then returned data is correct. Any ideas how to overcome this issue? I used PostgreSql database over Odbc connection.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they use different collations.  Some collations will ignore punctuation on a first pass, using it only if the values are otherwise equal.  Figure out which collation you want to use, then make sure both CR and PostgreSQL use that one.

Comment: Any idea how to set collation for CrystalReports? Tried to find such thing with no success so far.